# cognos active reports send to mobile device

Tags: ipad, mobile, report, cognos

I created an Active Report which should be sent to all mobile users.
There should be no difference in the report when i send it to different users.

So I created the report, afterwards went to Cognos Connection, run with options, selected the user which logs in on the IPAD Cognos BI App.
Next I logged in on the Cognos App, but there was no Report downloaded to my Reports.

Can anyone give me some advice how to solve this problem.
I'm using Cognos 10.2.1.

The Ipad can connect to the server. Its connected via VPN.
But i can browse and open/download all my active reports from within the IPad App, but i want to server to send it to my App so that not every user has to rerun the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Cognos Mobile Service installed on your server, when you schedule the report you will have an option to send the output to mobile devices.  Or you can just schedule the report, and then your users should be able to open that output instead of running the report.

Comment: The Problem is, that I send it to mobile Device and the server says: Sent to 1 Recipient and Logfiles doesnt show an error, BUT on the mobile device and on the /ibmcognos/m I dont get any result. Also used the schedule function, which gives me the same result as the "Run Report with options"

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have send it to mobile device or email client. There are two options for delivery. Also When you send it to mobile device did you select the user from the Authentication source. for e.g. Active Directory.

One other way to check is to email this report to your mobile device first and see if you are getting it via the email.

Comment: Tried both ways. Was in 2 phone calls with the IBM support. Changed some more things. First of all I needed to install 2 fixpacks for Bi and Mobile. Next some small changes in the IIS. Next install a separat content store for mobile. After the Inhouse IT will install the new Database it should work....That's what the IBM Support guy is telling me.